# video.insert failing silently with positive response and video id

Tags: insert, youtube-data-api

I am testing my python video upload script since 2 days.

Yesterday everything ok. Upload successful; then quota limit reached.

Today continue to test: insert/upload succeeds with response containing a video id, but the video with that id never appears on the channel. Also not visible in youtube studio.

I tried with 2 different videos - same thing and I have a id for all of them.
Now quota is again reached

uploaded but not visible ids e.g.: pSqyId96gTk, -kw-yn-qAxI

If I upload the same video in the Youtube WEB Frontend, everything is ok.

Any Idea how to analyse that problem?

here is part of the response dict:

```
{'kind': 'youtube#video', 
'etag': 'MgZ0r9Yu43ERF415Jw1lPRJgmDc',
'id': 'ZAuHewNcxL8', 
'snippet': 
     {'publishedAt': '2021-12-22T12:40:54Z', 
      'channelId': 'UCNSTNQqqGxwBqoOdekZPj_A',
        ...
     } 
'status': 
   {
    'uploadStatus': 'uploaded',
    'privacyStatus': 'private',
    'license': 'youtube',
    'embeddable': True, 
    'publicStatsViewable': True} 
 }
```

privacyStatus: "public" has the same effect.

Comment: How long is your video ? Because when accessing to https://youtu.be/pSqyId96gTk I have this message "Video unavailable This video was removed because it was too long"

Comment: thanks a lot for that url. I always tried the search function and there it is not found. The video is 30MB and 20minutes (shown in VLC in my PC). Interestingly I can upload much longer videos via WEB frontend. I there a limit via the API? My project has not yet undergone the google verification. I just started the project and it is my first contacts with the API. The pain point is, that there is a "200" success response.